# How to create app video using connected device or emulator?

Tags: android

I want to create the application video for play store. Is there a way to create app video using emulator or connected device?

Comment: You can use screen recorder for ur PC or device. there are lots of applications to use. for `Mac` u can use QuickTime for it!

Comment: Android Studio has that functionality under the 'Android-Monitor' (where you read your logs). Once there, look through the tool icons on the left. Over there you'll find the option for both recording video and taking a screenshot.

Comment: @KarthiVenture he said he needs *"to create the application video for play store"*

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with Android Studio, in the Android Monitor panel (if you don't see the panel you should be able to open it with alt+6)

[image: recordvideo]

If recording option is disable. Perform some prerequisites [click here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html#byb)
 and then follow the steps given [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-video.html)

Comment: from where i can get recorded screen video

Comment: after you have finished recording it will ask you where to save the file

Comment: it is showing the option. when i click on it nothing happens. My android studio version is 2.1.2.